# Free Look Camera Like Arma 2 while pressing ALT

Tags: unity, camera, first-person-shooter, unityscript

I'm trying to create a simple script that give me the possibility to rotate the camera while pressing a key. So, in a pseudo-code way, how I can intercept the Input event and limit the player's movements to hold the character direction?
I should tweak the MouseLook script? Or completely create a new one?

Comment: There are so many ways to do this you simply cannot get a single, good answer. Flagging this as too broad.

Comment: I know it, in fact i'm trying some other ways to do it. Now i've trying a "Game Object Based" solution based on 2 cameras as children of the character. It Works but is too much buggy and not completely extensible; for example i can't add a mouse input smoothing and the rotation sync of 2 cameras doesn't work as well every time. Just give me some solution. And remember that i'm new to unity :)

Comment: You misunderstood me. Your question is not appropriate to the site considering its current state. Pick a single solution and ask about that. Asking for suggestions or ideas is offtopic.

Answer (score 1):

If user is holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, do camera stuff, otherwise let player move as normal.

```
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightAlt)) {
        // Process mouse movement and camera rotation here 
    } else {
        // Process player movement here
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Create a C# Script and add it to your camera, change the Update() function to look like the above and then insert your camera movement logic as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe my question was not cleary. I know coding, but i'm new to unity and I would know where i should write this code, because i have a MouseLook, Character Motor and FPSInputCOntroller Script

Comment: @koMah Perhaps enable or disable the MouseLook or CharacterMotor scripts when Alt is changed (checked via `GetKeyDown` and `GetKeyUp`)? Create your own script, and in Unity's Script Execution Order pane, have your script be positioned before your MouseLook and CharacterMotor scripts.

Comment: Tried but it doesn't work. Other solution?

Comment: I would suggest if you don't know enough about Unity that you don't know where to put the Camera script to look at their [documentation and tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/stealth/camera-movement).